# Hadoop not utilizing available memory

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I have a 2 node cluster (each node having 32 GB RAM and 8 Cores).
I have installed CDH 5.4.
But I dont think the available memory is being utilized by hadoop, as the page :8088/cluster/apps shows up only 16 GB in "Memory Total" column.
Only once I could see that the "Memory Total " as 64GB, not sure whats going on.
What could be the reason?

Thanks,
Baahu

Comment: Did you install the 64 bit or the 32 bit OS? can you check and confirm back?

Answer (score 4):

You have to configure the memory that can be used per node for yarn. This setting is in yarn-site.xml. There are properties that governs the maximum memory that can be allocated for container allocation in the nodemanager. Seems like you are using a value of 8GB (default). Set the below property to a higher value.

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
```

Similarly for cores, there is another property

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores.
```

After setting these property in the yarn-site.xml of all the nodes, restart the yarn cluster. This will increase the nodemanager memory share. Along with this there are few more properties to tune the cluster. For more details, visit this [url](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html)

Comment: Bang on ! you were right. For some reason I thought this paramater was on per container basis and didn't bother to change it.Once I set it to 32GB, i could see it reflecting in the GUI as well.

Comment: These 2 configurations, if not configured, will use default of 8gb & 8 vcores respectively irrespective of what actually you have available on each node. So you should properly configure these settings to fully utilize the cluster.

Comment: Bang on target! The remaining memory is used by the disk cache.

Comment: I have a 4 Core 16 GB machine. The System monitor or the top command shows the the overall used memory is 9.x GB < 10 GB and 2 GB is used by swap but 3 GB is free. If I increase `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` i.e. `Container Memory` for Cloudera Manager, there is no effect.